# Update a document and subdocument with MEAN.js

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

I have a server-side update function in my MEAN.js project.
It takes in the request a quizz in req.quizz and the questions of this quizz in req.quizz.questions.

I can update my quizz, but not the questions of this quizz.

A Question is a subdocument of a Quizz, a Quizz can have multiple Questions.

My update function in my quizz.server.controller.js file is like this :

```
/**
 * Update a quizz
 */
exports.update = function(req, res) {
 var quizz = req.quizz;
 var quizz1 = req.quizz;

  quizz = _.extend(quizz, req.body);

  for (var i = quizz.questions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var question=quizz.questions[i];

      question = _.extend(question, req.body);

      quizz1.questions[i]=question;
      console.log('HERE');
      console.log(question);
      question.save();
  }

  quizz1 = _.extend(quizz1, req.body);

  quizz1.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.json(quizz1);
    }
});
};
```

My console.log(question); after "HERE" shows the new questions, but the question.save() function doesn't save this information in my DB. The quizz information is saved though.

Thanks !

Comment: Hi, show your req.body, your req.body containing the Quiz or Question? I am asking this because I see `quizz1 = _.extend(quizz1, req.body);` and `question = _.extend(question, req.body);`

Comment: Also if you do this `var quizz = req.quizz;
 var quizz1 = req.quizz;` this doesnt create 2 quiz objects, if you are changing something in quizz it will reflect in quizz1 as well